# Can't use Updater due to automatic kernel upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, updates, update-manager

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop ed. w/ kernel ver. 3.16
About a month ago I allowed the system to upgrade the kernel to ver. 4.xx, but after that I couldn't boot my system, so I re-installed everything from Clonezilla image and now I have again 3.16
It's all nice, but everyday I see this annoying upgrade proposal and what's even worse is that I think that I can't install any Ubuntu updates, since I get this kernel upgrade box and when I close it, then there's no update at all.
You can take a look at those two print screens I've added.

[that's how the upgrade box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86DTm.png)

[those are the options I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfMjy.png)

Answer (score 2):

That is because the Hardware Enablement Stack you are running has expired.  You need to update your HWE.  According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support the 3.16 kernel has expired for support and will no longer be updated.  However, the 3.13 kernel will continue until 14.04 EOL (Apr 2019).  Since you are running a kernel that is part of the HWE, the below information is the next step you can do.

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Trusty Tahr**

The 14.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel and X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can use the following to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (Xenial):

**Desktop**

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

Found at:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: My question is not how to install Ubuntu 16.04 or upgrade the kernel, but to how to get rid of the proposal for a kernel upgrade and use an Updater as I used it a year ago. I don't want to install 16.04 at the moment

Comment: @Gregory It is not upgrading to 16.04.  It is upgrading the HWE Kernels.  It will still be 14.04, but the support for the kernel that you are running that is part of the HWE has expired on support and will not be upgraded.

Comment: Are you saying that since I have 3.16 kernel, I can't get any updates, unless I upgrade the kernel to ver. 4.xx while keeping 14.04?

Comment: @Gregory Yes.  Because of the HWE it will not update any further.  http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life  I guess you could always try taking it back to a 3.13 kernel which would be the `linux-generic-lts-trusty` kernel.

Comment: @Gregory What does it tell you if you run a `sudo apt-get update` then a `sudo apt-get upgrade` from the terminal?

Comment: It's a good idea to try, generally speaking. But it's not what I'm gonna do, unless I'm ready to spend a day doing restorations of everything if again I'll end up with 14.04 and kernel 4.4 and not a booting system. (I have a dual boot system with W10). Also I can always try to simply upgrade to 16.04 with PHP7, but again... Granted if I have the time to waste if things won't work as they should with my scripts, which might not work as expected with a newer PHP version.

Comment: Someone gave me an idea of downgrading my kernel from 3.16 to 3.13, so it would be supported till the end. I'm using 14.04.1

Comment: Another idea was to use Synaptic. I usually preferred not to use it and go with a default option.

Comment: @Gregory `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not upgrade kernels, it only does applications.  `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will do the kernels as well.  It was my suggestion to maybe go back to 3.13 kernel since it is supported till Apr 2019 when 14.04 goes EOL.